# Relativistic beaming - which power of the Doppler factor

Tags: simulations, relativity, doppler-effect

The context is that I'm building a simulation of a starfield, as seen from a relativistic spaceship. (EDIT: the simulation can now be found [here](http://tinyurl.com/pt8h6j4).)

One reference that I'm using is this paper by John M. McKinley (1980) "Relativistic transformation of solid angle":

http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1980AmJPh..48..612M

http://cartan.e-moka.net/content/download/248/1479/file/Astronave%20relativistica.pdf

There are two formulas, one with D^2, and one with D^4 (D being the Doppler factor). The logic stated by the above paper seems to be the following:

Use D^2 for:

- comparing two detectors in relative motion
- plane waves
- stars

Use D^4 for:

- comparing a moving source of radiation, relative to a fixed source
- extended sources: galaxies, cosmic microwave background, astrophysical jets, and so on

Question: is the above breakdown of when to use D^2 versus D^4 correct?

Here is the last paragraph of the paper in its entirety:

> It is hoped that this presentation can clarify the role of 
>   the solid-angle transformation. Because it is a necessary 
>   consequence of aberration, there is always a change in the 
>   solid angle associated with light when one changes reference 
>   frame (except for the case of idealized plane waves). Its
>   effect effect upon the transformation of intensity must be included
>   in the study of cosmic microwave background radiation, where the 
>   angle is associated with convergence into the detector of 
>   radiation from different parts of the primordial fireball. It
>   must also be included when a moving source is compared 
>   to an equivalent fixed source, both at the same apparent 
>   distance measured in the reference frame of the detector.
>   In this case the angle represents divergence from the compact
>   source to the detector. The change in solid angle does
>   not contribute to the transformation of intensity measured
>   at the same event point by detectors in relative motion. Note 
>   particularly that the amount of divergence of the light, or 
>   equivalently the curvature of the wavefronts, does not 
>   determine which intensity transformation is correct. Thus, in 
>   considering the appearance of stars from a moving spaceship,
>   a typical source distance is 1-1000 pc but the intensity 
>   transformation is equivalent to that for plane waves. On the 
>   other hand, typical receding galaxies are 10^6 times further 
>   away (so their light can is actually more nearly plane), but
>   their light cannot be treated as plane waves in finding its
>   intensity transformation.